# Foursquare follow button listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, foursquare

Hi i'm trying to get a listener for the foursquare save button by using the fsquare.widget.
But the documentation on the site is very short so I can't figure it out. Here's my code any idea's?

```
<!-- Place this anchor tag where you want the button to go -->
<a data-on-load="javascript:test();" href="https://foursquare.com/intent/venue.html"   class="fourSq-widget" data-variant="wide">Save to foursquare</a>

<!-- Place this script somewhere after the anchor tag above. If you have multiple buttons, only include the script once. -->
<script type='text/javascript'>
(function() {
    window.___fourSq = {
        "explicit": false,
        "onReady": function () {
            var widget = new fourSq.widget.SaveTo();
            fourSq.widget.Events.bind("follow", function(){
            //wish something like this worked
                 alert('test');
        });
        }
    };
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.type = 'text/javascript';
    s.src = 'http://platform.foursquare.com/js/widgets.js';
    s.async = true;
    var ph = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    ph.parentNode.insertBefore(s, ph);
})();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm just guessing, but maybe it helps:

This is your(foursquares') code:

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>
(function() {
    window.___fourSq = {
        "explicit": false,
        "onReady": function () {
            var widget = new fourSq.widget.SaveTo();
            fourSq.widget.Events.bind("follow", function(){
            //wish something like this worked
                 alert('test');
        });
        }
    };
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.type = 'text/javascript';
    s.src = 'http://platform.foursquare.com/js/widgets.js';
    s.async = true;
    var ph = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    ph.parentNode.insertBefore(s, ph);
})();
</script>
```

Maybe it helps to add:

```
"onSaveTo": function () {
        alert("Dunno if that works :D");
    });
    }
```

Hope it works. If someone knows the real answer i will delete this.

Comment: Do you just want to get the onclick action, i dont really get what onsave does in this context? If you only want to do that you could set a cookie to save if a user has pressed the button